# Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 5742G

Tags: acer

I visited the list of laptops that support Ubuntu on this website and none of the Acer laptops was listed as supportive. So my question is: can i use Ubuntu on my laptop ? - if so, which version should i choose so that all the features work ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specifications of the system, you can definitely install Ubuntu on it.  You may have to install graphics driver, and if that's the case, instructions are [Here](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

I would recommend that you install [Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  I also recommend that you try it, before installing, just to make sure that it works with the hardware.

Once downloaded, you can either create a bootable DVD or USB drive.  For more information on that, and on the installation as a whole take a look at [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)